# 'Syntax Error' when using Database Navigator for PyCharm

Tags: mysql, casting, pycharm

I have a project with a MySQL database to which I connected using the Database Navigator plugin.

Now when I open the DB Browser window, select the database and click on "Open DB console" and insert the query

`SELECT CAST('2017-08-29' AS DATE);`

for one, the IDE highlights `CAST` as an unknown identifier:

[image: unknown identifier]

and, additionally, when I try to execute the statement, I get the error

`Error executing SELECT statement. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 - Connection: test: 112ms`

However, to my knowledge, this is valid MySQL, at least [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp) page suggests so.

I am also able to perform MySQL queries with casts from a python script that builds the connection itself.

What am I doing wrong here? Do I have to configure the dialect for Database Navigator?